# How do I make a webpage be different for a superuser and a normal user on django?

Tags: django, superuser

Let me explain a little, I'm trying to make a website just for practicing, in which you have two sides, customer-side, and admin-side, so I want to make certain pages display certain functions when you are logged in as an admin, and to not display said functions to normal users, such as edits and stuff. How do I do that?

I hope I explained it properly.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Django provides an admin panel?

Comment: Yes, maybe I didn't explained my self as I wanted to. I want to make certain pages to only be accesible for admin users, so normal users of that website, can't acces them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, Here is what you have asked for

in your template

## hello.html

```
{% if user.is_superuser or user.is_staff %}
This section only visible to superuser and staff
This section not accessible to normal users
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I will try that! Thanks

Comment: if my solution is working give me a tick and upvote my answer

Comment: Done, although when I click on the upvote it says this: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."